# How to solve ReferenceError: gapi is not defined problem in the Next.js application?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-api, next.js

I want add Google API (`gapi`) to a `Next.js` (*node.js based*) application.

So I used `npm install --save @types/gapi` to install the related package in my app.

[image]

But I front with the following errors:

- **When I use** `import 'gapi' from '@types/gapi'`**:**

> **Error  »** Module not found: Can't resolve '@types/gapi'

- **When I don't use** `import 'gapi' from '@types/gapi'`**:**

> **Error  »** ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

**What is the reason of this error and how can I solve it?**

Actually I want authenticated with `auth2` by `gapi` after it and continue. If you know a good related sample please reference me here too please.

My codes in `pages/api/test.ts`:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

   
export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {

  function start() {
    gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': '*********',
      'discoveryDocs': ['https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'],
      'clientId': '***********',
      'scope':'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'
    }).then(function() {
      return "xxxxxxxxx";    
    }).then(function(response:any) {
       console.log(response);          
    }, function(reason:any) {
      console.log('Error: ' + reason );
    })
  };

  gapi.load('client', start);

}
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: any update on if it is '@types/gapi' or '@types/gapi2'?